# How to stop receiving values on a closed channel?

Tags: go

I have the following somewhat similar code executing after an API request.
When that API call is executing, if I get a SIGINT I want to do some clean up activity. If I do not receive any signal then I want to close the `sigs` channel using `done` channel.

But even after doing so when I stop my server using `Ctrl+C`. It panics as `panic: send on closed channel.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "syscall"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")

    sigs := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(sigs, syscall.SIGINT, syscall.SIGTERM)
    done := make(chan bool, 1)
    go func() {
        for {
            select {

            case val, ok := <-sigs:
                if !ok {
                    return
                }
                fmt.Println("Hello", val, ok)
            case <-done:
                close(sigs)
                return

            }

        }
    }()

    done <- true

    time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
}
```

So basically if my API is working properly it should close the channel after completion.
And if it is stopped abruptly it should do some cleanup.

Can anybody point out what I am doing wrong?

If I run the above code in playground it will first close the channel and then kill the program because of timeout which sends SIGTERM or SIGINT again, which causes panic!!!

**Answer** : I guess my question was not clear but still got some useful info from users. My issue was even after closing channel the program was sending signals to that channel. So the simplest solution I found is that I needed to stop the channel from receiving using `signal.Stop(sigs)` and then return from that goroutine. So ...

```
case _, ok := <-sigs :
    if !ok {
        // after closing channel
        signal.Stop(sigs)
        return
    }
   // if any signal is received
    os.Exit(0)
```

Comment: You do not need to close `sigs`. So there is no problem.

Comment: Yes I need to close it. But even after closing, it is still receiving.

Comment: "How to stop receiving values on a closed channel?" This is absolutely impossible. All you can do is not _send_ on a closed channel. But that is a totally different thing.

Comment: Why do you think that you need to close `sigs`?

Comment: @super Does it not consume any resources by keeping it open?

Comment: @CriticalRebel which "resources" might be consumed by "keeping it open" once  you program is terminated? To repeat what icza told you: "You do not need to close sigs. So there is no problem."

Comment: @CriticalRebel: even _if_ your program were not exiting immediately, closing a channel is not a cleanup operation! From the [Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/4): "Channels aren't like files; you don't usually need to close them. Closing is only necessary when the receiver must be told there are no more values coming, such as to terminate a range loop."

Answer (score 2):

What happens here is that you close `sig` channel and then a `SIGINT` happens when you press `Ctrl+C`, and then the go runtime tries to push to the `sig` channel but it's closed. So naturally, a `panic` happens.
I believe you shouldn't close the `sig` channel, ever.

Comment: But because of that it is holding an API request.

Comment: @CriticalRebel I don't think that's your problem. What do you mean by "it's holding an API request"?

Comment: @super Ok my bad. It is not actually holding the API. I am executing this code after each API request. I just want to exit this goroutine and never receive any signals after successfully close the sigs channel.

Comment: @CriticalRebel then just `return`. No need to close the `sig`. By returning you exit the goroutine.

Comment: @HamedMomeni What happens to the goroutine if I never receive any OS signal?

Comment: @CriticalRebel Nothing, if neither chans receive anything, the goroutine just blocks forever (until the main goroutine exits).

Comment: Sorry for dumb question but If my code is server in which the main goroutine never terminates then what will happen to that goroutine?

Comment: It's alright :). Well as I mentioned earlier, it blocks forever. Meaning it waits until a value is received on either channels.

Comment: Thanks for the answers :)  Though I found out a different solution